# what's the correct way to develop at the repl using groovy

Tags: groovy, eclipse-plugin, read-eval-print-loop

I'm new to working with Groovy. I'm used to Python and Clojure where I could do most of my coding at the REPL. I'm trying to do the same with Groovy, but I'm not sure if I've found a way that matches up.

The Groovy Eclipse plugin provides a couple of interactive modes but neither seems to cut it for me.

The first way loads a Groovy script into the Groovy Console. The console appears to me as a weak editor without any of the amenities of Eclipse, such as tab completion. There are some nice introspection capabilities, but it doesn't really feel like interactive development.

The second way starts a Groovy Shell in the console tab of Eclipse. So this gives me the REPL I want, but it feels really clunky running in Eclipse. There's no tab completion. And I have to type "go" after entering in code I want it to evaluate.

The Groovy Eclipse plugin wasn't cutting it, but the Groovy shell included in the stand alone distribution of Groovy works great. It does tab completion (except for classnames), and it evaluates code right after you type it in. It's the one that documented [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell).

I dug a little deeper into the differences between the REPL that runs in Eclipse and the one that runs from the stand alone distribution using the *groovysh* script. The one from Eclipse is an instance of *'groovy.ui.InteractiveShell'* and the one from the *groovysh* script is and instance of *'org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main'*. And I found the following code in the *groovysh* script

```
if [ "x$OLDSHELL" != "x" ]; then </br>
    startGroovy groovy.ui.InteractiveShell "$@"
else
    startGroovy org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main "$@"
fi
```

The above code and [this thread](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Missing-UI-Classes-in-1-9-Betas-td4832237.html) tell me groovy.ui.InteractiveShell is going away.

Perhaps there are plans to integrate the new shell more tightly into Eclipse in the future?

Anyways, I was able to hack it out so that I could call the *groovysh* script with the classpaths needed for working with code from my Eclipse project. Now I can develop happily at the REPL. But it's messy and I'm using the jars in the Groovy stand-alone distribution for starting up Groovy instead of the ones used my Eclipse project. I figure there might be a better way.

Has anyone found a good way integrate the REPL the gets started from the *groovysh* script and a project in Eclipse. Or have you found an overall better way to develop with a Groovy REPL?

Comment: So it turns out that you can add a classpath to the groovysh script by just doing "./groovysh -cp dir1:dir2:jar1:jar2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much effort has gone into integrating groovysh into groovy-eclipse.  The main reason is that groovysh uses all sorts of non-display characters to specify things like color, completion, and caret placement.  The Eclipse console does not handle these and spits them out as garbage.  Furthermore, the current shell implementation from Groovy does not run very well on windows when inside Eclipse.  There are some incompatibilities with the jline library.

If we were to do some integration with groovysh, it would be a large undertaking and a large rewrite.  I am not against doing something like this, but so far no one has asked for the feature (you are the first that I am aware of).

What is wrong with running groovysh from the command line while you work in Eclipse?  (This is not a rhetorical question, I really do want to know what features are missing.)  This is the technique that most Groovy developers use when working inside of Eclipse.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your answer. Working with groovysh from the command line is working out fine. I just want to make sure there wasn't an other way. The one thing that does bug me is that I have to run groovysh with a big -cp argument. I don't think there's a way to automatically get my project's runtime class path from Eclipse. But that's no biggie, I can just do a 'ps' to figure it out or look at the '.classpath' file. And groovy shell lets me easily eval a file. And thats working great for debugging. Groovy overall is great, and it's a lot of fun. Thanks for your work on it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good way to launch the groovysh in ITerm with a custom classpath from Eclipse. It is specific to OSX and ITerm, but you could modify it to call a different shell depending on how you pass a string to the shell for it to execute.

---

Setup an external tool in Eclipse that calls a script. The script uses ITerm's applescript commands to open a new ITerm window and executes the command passed in.

The text of the arguments box in the image below:

> "cd ${project_loc} &&  /Users/harishtella/Developer/groovy/groovy-1.8.6/bin/groovysh -cp ${project_loc}/bin:${project_loc}/src:${project_loc}/lib/*:${project_loc}/test"

The ${project_loc} variable is available when defining new external tools. See [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-exttools.htm) for more info.

[image]

Be sure to uncheck the "allocate console" box in the "Common" tab

[image]

here's is the body of the "iterm-with-command" script

```
#!/bin/sh
# open a new iterm window and runs all the arguments passed in as a command
# in iterm
osascript <<-eof
tell application "iTerm"
    set myterm to (make new terminal)
tell myterm
    launch session "Default session"
        tell the last session
            set name to "console"
            write text "$@"
end tell
end tell
end tell
eof
```